# wkwebview won't display a youtube video in an iframe

Tags: ios, youtube, wkwebview

I am trying to use a WKWebView under iOS 9 and one of the pages happens to have a youtube video in an iframe. The video does not display. The same video works in Safari so doesn't seem to be an iOS issue, I assume I am missing a configuration option in the view. A sample URL is http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_youtubeiframe.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate
{
    var webView : WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let webviewConfiguration                       = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webviewConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        webviewConfiguration.preferences.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
        webviewConfiguration.allowsAirPlayForMediaPlayback       = true
        webviewConfiguration.allowsPictureInPictureMediaPlayback = true
        webviewConfiguration.requiresUserActionForMediaPlayback  = false
        webView                    = WKWebView(frame: self.view.bounds,
            configuration: webviewConfiguration)
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        self.view                  = webView
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_youtubeiframe")
        let req = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        self.webView!.loadRequest(req)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func webView(webView: WKWebView,
        didFailNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!,
        withError error: NSError)
    {
        print("didFailNavigation \(error)")
    }

    func webView(webView: WKWebView,
        didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!,
        withError error: NSError)
    {
        print("didFailProvisionalNavigation  \(error)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to  Projects info.plist file
Added a Key called NSAppTransportSecurity as a Dictionary.
Added a Subkey called NSAllowsArbitraryLoads as Boolean and set its value to YES. It works.[image]

Comment: D'Oh! Thanks. I added exceptions for the server but didn't clue in that, of course, youtube is also http and needed an exception... been a long day :-) Be nice if apple spit out an error in that case!